# Writing labels for 'Traefik' (proxy server) using 'Ansible'

Tags: ansible, traefik, converters

I am trying to convert docker-compose file into Ansible playbook.
The challenge that I have is how to write the labels in ansible format.

The docker compose file below:

```
   - name: run search container
     docker_container:
       name: search
       image: docker-registry.xxxdev.xxxx.com/soxx/sxxxna-search:latest
       volumes:
         - /exec-ui/app-config/application.yml:/opt/xxxna-search/config/application.yml
         - /exec-ui/app-config/logback.xml:/opt/xxxna-search/config/logback.xml
       ports:
         - "9090:9090"
       labels:
         - "traefik.port=9090"
         - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/search/xxxxx
```

I'm using ansible 2.4.2.0
Thanks for the help

Yaniv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

Just remove the '-' and ' "" ' as follows

Before the change:

```
   labels:
     - "traefik.port=9090"
     - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/search/xxxxx
```

After the change to ansible playbook:

```
   labels:
      traefik.port: "9090"
      traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefix:/search/,/xxxx
```